# Symfony 2.7 composer update swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, swiftmailer, symfony-2.7

I had the following composer.json working for years in a Symfony2 project

```
{
"name": "sima/api",
  "license": "Private",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "SIMA API",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": "src/",
      "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/SymfonyStandard/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^1.7",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.9",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.0",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "^1.5",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^2.8",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~2.0@dev",
    "phpunit/phpunit" : "4.8.3",
    "willdurand/rest-extra-bundle": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.2",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^0.14.0",
    "cspoo/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.0",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.0",
    "pelago/emogrifier": "@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master",
    "eightpoints/guzzle-bundle": "^4.5",
    "box/spout": "^2.7",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I do composer update I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class
>   'Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle' not found in
>   C:\Git\web\app\AppKernel.php on line 16 Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

Tried in two different environments using PHP 5.6.25 and 5.6.30

Tried removing vendors directory

Tried composer install

Comment: Looks like this class `Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache` is triggering an Exception. Those are post install and update scripts. Seems this one is referencing a class that's not there any more.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I Accidentally removed "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3", from composer.json